# How to step reader.readLine() in two for cycles ?

Tags: java

I am reading data from a txt file. I want to create new objects from every ten lines and "." indicates that the current object doesn't have any more data lines (I work with two types of object("Nemfuggetlen" and "fuggetlen"), "fuggetlen" has 9 and "Nemfuggetlen" has 7 lines, "." separates their data lines).

The problem is: when I read two "Nemfuggetlen" objects in a row, it works fine, but if I read "fuggetlen" after "Nemfuggetlen" it makes "-------" to the next object first data lines, when it shouldn't. For "Nemfuggetlen" object it should fill the last 3 lines of "adatok" string array with "-------" and step to the next object.

```
int sorokszama = 0;
    input.mark(300); 
    while((s = input.readLine()) !=null){ 
    sorokszama++; 
    System.out.println("Sorok szama : " + sorokszama);
    input.reset(); 

    for(int h = 0; h < sorokszama/10; h++){
        for(int i = 0;(s = input.readLine()) !=null; i++) {
            if(i < 10){
                if(!(".".equals(s))) {
                    adatok[i] = s;
                    System.out.println(adatok[i]);
            } 
                else {
                    adatok[i] = "-------";
                    System.out.println(adatok[i]);
                    break;
            }   
        }       
    }
        if("Ferfi".equals(adatok[2])){ 
            nem = true;
        }
        else {
            nem = false;
        }

        if("Van".equals(adatok[4])){
            tamogato = true;
        }
        else{
            tamogato = false;
        }
        if("-------".equals(adatok[7])){    //A kepviselo nem fuggetlen
        k = new Nemfuggetlen(adatok[0], Integer.parseInt(adatok[1]), nem, adatok[4], new Kerulet (Integer.parseInt(adatok[5])), adatok[6]);
        }
        if("-------".equals(adatok[9])){ // A kepviselo fuggetlen
        k = new Fuggetlen(adatok[0], Integer.parseInt(adatok[1]), nem, adatok[4], new Kerulet (Integer.parseInt(adatok[5])),tamogato, adatok[7], Integer.parseInt(adatok[8]));
        }

        kepviselok.add(k);
        //System.out.println(kepviselok.get(0));
    }
    System.out.println("Kepviselok szama : " + sorokszama/10);
    for(int i = 0; i < kepviselok.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println((i+1) + ". tag : " + kepviselok.get(i));
    }
    input.close();
```

Comment: Why do you say you create "objects from every ten lines" when some of them are 8 lines (7 plus the ".") and some of them are 10 lines (9 plus the ".")?

Comment: There is something deeply confusing about the relationship between sorokszama, h, and i. I strongly suspect the logic is faulty, but it is so confusing it is impossible to tell. Step through it in a debugger and/or write out your logic in pseudocode and hand emulate it.